# Why is pid of child process and parent process the same?

Tags: process, fork, parent-child, pid

i am tryng to check the pid for the parent and child process, but whenever i run the program what i get is the same pid value for both of them.

from what i know getpid gets the pid of current process. Am i wrong? [same valur of pid for both processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNiZO.png)

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>


    int main (void){

pid_t pid= fork(); 
switch (pid){ 
case -1: 
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
        break;
case 0 :
    printf("Child Process - my pid: %d, my parent's pid: %d\n", (int)getpid, (int)getppid);
    break;
default : 
    wait();
    printf("parent process - my pid: %d, my parent's pid: %d, my child's pid: %d\n", (int)getpid, (int)getppid, (int)pid);
    break;}


    printf("End of fork\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called the `getpid` or `getppid` functions, you've only cast them to integers. You need to add parentheses.

```
printf("parent process - my pid: %d, my parent's pid: %d, my child's pid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), pid);
```

Notice the bad values being printed are well outside the PID range, which is [typically 32k](https://serverfault.com/questions/279178/what-is-the-range-of-a-pid-on-linux-and-solaris). Your parent process is printing the correct child PID because that value is an integer when it's handed to you.